# Mostrar dados Json dentro de um Form Html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, laravel-5

Tenho uma Grid com o botão editar quando clico nela ela acessa o Controller e traz os dados em um Json e "Teoricamente" era pra retornar esses dados em um Modal.

Quando digito a Url ....show/(ID) os dados do Json aparece mas não estou conseguindo fazer esses dados aparecer no Form do Modal.

Segue o Código

**HTML (Botão e Inputs aonde os dados eram para aparecer)**

```
<a href="#"  onclick="GetAlunoDetails('{{$valor->id}}')" data-target="#editModal" data-toggle="modal">{{ $valor->nome }}</a>


<input type="text"  class="form-control" id='nometeste'  name="nometeste" value="">

<input type="text"  class="form-control" id='idteste'  name="idteste" value="">

<input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
```

**JS**

```
 function GetAlunoDetails(id) {

    $("#hidden_user_id").val(id);
    $.get("/.../alunos/show/"+id, {

        },
        function (data) {
            // PARSE json data
            var aluno = JSON.parse(data);
            // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
            $("#nometeste").val(aluno.nome);
            $("#idteste").val(aluno.id);


        }
    );
    // Open modal popup
    $("#editModal").modal("modal");
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function show($id)
{


//Pegando os valores para preencher a tabela
$aluno= $this->aluno
    ->select('*')
    ->find($id);

return response()->json($aluno);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Problema pode está na sua consulta ao model. Assumindo que você tem um model que se chama 'Aluno'. Ao invés de fazer `$aluno= $this->aluno->select('*')->find($id);` faça `$aluno = Aluno::find($id);`.

Espero ajudar

Comment: Eu ja fiz um teste e o retorno do Json no Controller está funcionando só que eu nao consigo passar pro HTML

Comment: Você está conseguindo abrir o modal pelo menos? Já tentou abrir o modal e depois colocar os dados nos campos?

Comment: Sim o Modal está abrindo normal

Comment: Tenta abrir o modal dentro da função de retorno. Essa chamada é assincrona e por isso pode ter o delay de ir no servidor e voltar, ocasionando esse problema.